# pandas equivalent select count(distinct col1, col2) group by col3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Make DataFrame:

```
people = ['shayna','shayna','shayna','shayna','john']
dates = ['01-01-18','01-01-18','01-01-18','01-02-18','01-02-18']
places = ['hospital', 'hospital', 'inpatient', 'hospital', 'hospital']
d = {'Person':people,'Service_Date':dates, 'Site_Where_Served':places}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df

Person   Service_Date   Site_Where_Served
shayna   01-01-18       hospital 
shayna   01-01-18       hospital 
shayna   01-01-18       inpatient 
shayna   01-02-18       hospital 
john     01-02-18       hospital
```

What I would like to do is count the unique pairs of Person and their Service_Date grouped by Site_Where_Served.

Expected Output:

```
Site_Where_Served    Site_Visit_Count
hospital             3
inpatient            1
```

---

My attempt:

```
df[['Person', 'Service_Date']].groupby(df['Site_Where_Served']).nunique().reset_index(name='Site_Visit_Count')
```

But then it doesn't know how to reset the index. So, I tried leaving that out and I realize that it isn't counting the unique pair of 'Person' and 'Service_Date', because the output looks like this:

```
                   Person    Service_Date
Site_Where_Served
hospital              2           2 
inpatient             1           1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `drop_duplicates` with `groupby` + `count`

```
(df.drop_duplicates()
   .groupby('Site_Where_Served')
   .Site_Where_Served.count()
   .reset_index(name='Site_Visit_Count')
)

  Site_Where_Served  Site_Visit_Count
0          hospital                 3
1         inpatient                 1
```

Note, one tiny difference between `count`/`size` is that the former does not count NaN entries.

---

#### Tuplization, `groupby` and `nunique`

This is really only fixing your current solution, but I would not recommend this as it is quite long winded with more steps than necessary. First, tuplize your columns, group by `Site_Where_Served`, and then count:

```
(df[['Person', 'Service_Date']]
   .apply(tuple, 1)
   .groupby(df.Site_Where_Served)
   .nunique()
   .reset_index(name='Site_Visit_Count')
)

  Site_Where_Served  Site_Visit_Count
0          hospital                 3
1         inpatient                 1
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, a better way is to drop duplicates before using `groupby.size`:

```
res = df.drop_duplicates()\
        .groupby('Site_Where_Served').size()\
        .reset_index(name='Site_Visit_Count')

print(res)

  Site_Where_Served  Site_Visit_Count
0          hospital                 3
1         inpatient                 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `value_counts`

```
(df.drop_duplicates()
   .Site_Where_Served
   .value_counts()
   .to_frame('Site_Visit_Count')
   .rename_axis('Site_Where_Served')
   .reset_index()
)

  Site_Where_Served  Site_Visit_Count
0          hospital                 3
1         inpatient                 1
```

Comment: Yeah, but this isn't a complete answer—Needs some more surgery for OP's exact expected outuput

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yep , should complete my answer before posted , thanks mate

Comment: Yup, it looks perfect now.

Answer (score 1):

### `Counter` 1

```
pd.Series(Counter(df.drop_duplicates().Site_Where_Served)) \
    .rename_axis('Site_Where_Served').reset_index(name='Site_Visit_Count')

  Site_Where_Served  Site_Visit_Count
0          hospital                 3
1         inpatient                 1
```

---

### `Counter` 2

```
pd.DataFrame(
    list(Counter(t[2] for t in set(map(tuple, df.values))).items()),
    columns=['Site_Where_Served', 'Site_Visit_Count']
)

  Site_Where_Served  Site_Visit_Count
0          hospital                 3
1         inpatient                 1
```

Comment: Oh man, with our answers together I look like a cheap piR ripoff

Comment: Give me break!  Looks like two great answers (-: